# WPF - How to implement INotifyPropertyChanged when Properties are dynamic

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a business object that implements a collection of PropertyObjects.

BusinessObject
   SomeCollection
       Property1Object (Name=Height)
       Property2Object (Name=Width)

Currently, I am setting the DataContext of UserControl to be the BusinessObject.  I've found that I CAN reference into the collection in the binding with something like this, say in a textBox..

UserControl.DataContext = BusinessObject
UserControl.TextBlock
      **Text="{Binding Collection[Height].Value}"**

Now, at what level can I properly implement INotifyPropertyChanged, even though at the higher level it isn't a property at all.

It's easy enough to see and raise the at the lowest level, the PropertyObject, but is that enough for the binding to work?

Thanks,
jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, every object in the `Collection` array has a property called `Value`, which is what is displayed in the `TextBlock` in your `UserControl`. As long as each object in the array implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and fires the event when the value of `Value` changes, the text in the `TextBlock` should update (you might need to change the `BindingMode` to `TwoWay` as well, I'm not sure though).

Answer (score 0):

If you're fake implementing your own collection, you need to implement INotifyCollectionChanged (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx)